# Limit question on independent random variables (Exercise 4.2.4 from Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\{X_r | r \geq 1\}$ be independent and identically distributed with distribution function $F$ satisfying $F(y) < 1$ for all $y$, and let $Y(y) = \min \{k | X_k > y\}$. Show that
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} P(Y(y) \leq E[Y(y)]) = 1 - e^{-1}.
$$

I managed to show that $E[Y(y)] = \alpha(y) = (1 - F(y))^{-1}$ and that
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} P(Y(y) \leq E[Y(y)]) = \lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^{\lfloor \alpha(y) \rfloor} {\lfloor \alpha(y) \rfloor \choose i} (-1)^{i+1} \alpha(y)^{-i} \right).
$$
And the expression on the right, according to Mathematica, does indeed seem to converge to $1 - e^{-1}$. But how can I show that this is true? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Write your expression this way (abbreviating $\alpha(y)$ as $\alpha$ and $\lfloor\alpha(y)\rfloor$ as $n$):
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{n\choose i}(-1)^{i+1}\alpha^{-i}=1-\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}(-1)^{i}\alpha^{-i}=1-\sum_{i=0}^n{n\choose i}\left(-\frac1\alpha\right)^i(1)^{n-i}$$
and apply the binomial theorem. Then note that as $y\to\infty$ we have $n\to\infty$ and $n/\alpha\to1$.

Answer (score 1):

$Y(y)$ is a geometric random variable: the number of independent Bernoulli trials until the first success, where on each trial we have success with probability $p = 1 - F(y)$.  We may as well think of $p$ as the parameter rather than $y$.  Note that $0 < p < 1$, with $p \to 0$ as $y \to \infty$.  So $\mathbb E[Y] = 1/p$.  For any integer $n$, $P(Y \le n)$ is the probability of at least one success in the first $n$ trials, thus $1 - (1-p)^n$.  Taking $n = \lfloor 1/p \rfloor$,
$$ \mathbb P(Y \le 1/p) = \mathbb P(Y \le n) = 1 - (1-p)^n = 1 - \exp(n \log(1-p))$$

But $n \log(1-p) = n (-p + O(p^2)) = -1 + O(p)$